# Changing color of LED notification every 5 seconds

Tags: android

I'm trying to turn on the LED notification, for example the green color. Turn the screen off, and every 5 seconds change that color to red (green->red, red->green). I think I've done everything: in a service I created a timer which executes method to display notification.

```
public class LEDService extends Service
{
private boolean TimerStarted;
private Timer timer;
private NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
private long LastColor;

public TurnLedOn()
{
     Notification notify = new Notification();
     notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
     notify.LedOnMS = 500;
     notify.LedOffMS = 0;
     //I in other example I also used array of colors
     if (LastColor == 0x00FF00) notify.LedARGB = 0xFF0000; else notify.LedARGB = 0x00FF00;         
     LastColor = notify.LedARGB;
}

private MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        TurnLedOn();
    }
}

@Override
public void OnCreate()
{
    TimerStarted = false;
    myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    if (TimerStarted == false)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 0, 5000);
    }        
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind()
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    timer.close();
}
}
```

What is the problem? The LED doesn't change its color... When I turn the screen off, the color is green until I turn on the screen and turn it off again. I want to start this service once, turn off the screen and see the LED light changing color :).

BTW: I tested my phone and it CAN show green and red lights so it's not the problem.

Thank in advance and sorry for my English.

**I can't answer to my own question so I'll add this here:**

Thanks for your suggestions **Olsavage**, I added clearAll() to my code, but effect is still the same ;/. I also added logging to my application (Log.i() ). **It looks like the system is stopping my service when I turn the screen off (why??)**. It is something this way:

Screen Turned On:
The timer is running and notification is deployed (but I can't see led on, because to see it i have to turn the screen off :P )

Click on the lock button:
The timer is almost stopped, so the LED sometimes changes color once.

Screen is turned Off:
The timer is not working, TurnLedOn method is not running anymore. LED doesn't change colors.

Now the question is: **why my service is stopped after turning the screen off**? Even when I am doing simple operation in it (like incrementing a variable). Maybe I have to set its priority or something?

I changed the timer interval to 100ms and see that code is good. The LED changed colors for 5-15 times but then immediately stopped. I know that this application is completely useless but I just want to let it working :).

EDIT2:
I think I will have to use AlarmManager and PendingIntent to launch my service... Tomorrow I will try to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I figured it out. Removed the timer at all. Instead I use AlarmManager :).

I added to onCreate following code:

```
alarmmgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

in onStartCommand:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
 TurnLedOn();   //Turn LED On
 myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent. FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);   
 alarmmgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000, myPendingIntent); //Setting alarm to be off after 5seconds.
 return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

in onDestroy:

```
public void onDestroy() 
{
notifymgr.cancel(LED_NOTIFICATION_ID);  //Clearing notification
alarmmgr.cancel(myPendingIntent);   //Clear alarm
}
```

I think code is ok but I'm totally beginner in Android programming. I think I solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ARGB format. Try to set 0xFFFF0000 - red and 0xFF00FF00 - green. Hope this helps.

Hm, maybe your old notification didn't cleared? Try to use myNotificationManager.clearAll(); Before myNotificationManager.notify(0, notify);

Oh, also, try to set notify.ledOffMS = 5000;

Comment: It already displays right color :) The problem is, that it doesn't change color when the screen is turned off. To change color I have to turn screen of my phone and turn it off... I want to change color automaticly.